# How do I deal with view getting either ActiveRecord object or array of hashes returned to it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, activerecord, hash

I have this chunk of code that returns either an ActiveRecord object or and array of hashes. The first "if" returns an arrays of hashes via sql query

```
 if @parts_search_ids.any?
          @part_groups = Kaminari.paginate_array(PartGroup.search_part_groups(@parts_search_ids)).page(params[:page]).per(25)
          # @part_groups = Kaminari.paginate_array(PartGroup.search_part_groups(@parts_search_ids)).page(params[:page]).per(25)
          # @part_groups = PartGroup.parts_group_by_name(@parts_search_ids).page(params[:page]).per(25)
        elsif @filter == 'all_parts'
          @part_groups = Kaminari.paginate_array(PartGroup.all).page(params[:page]).per(25)
        else
          @part_groups = Kaminari.paginate_array([]).page(params[:page]).per(25)
        end
```

So depending on the condition I have I get either:

```
part_group = {"name"=>"170128", "part_category"=>"0", "critical_part"=>"f", "part_groups_count"=>"1", "project"=>"CW01"}
```

or

```
part_group = #<PartGroup id: 1249, name: "KIT.LTE.OVLY.HUA.3CAR", part_category_id: 278, created_at: "2013-12-03 01:32:32", updated_at: "2013-12-03 01:32:32", always_show_group: false, critical_part: false>
```

as I loop through the part_groups array of hashes I get:

> undefined method `name' for #

What is the best way to deal with this?

Comment: you could do a check before you loop through, by saying `part_group.is_a?(Array)`

Comment: I think @evanbikes has the right answer- making your returns consistent. Also, it's probably a good idea to handle that at the end of your method through a common variable in case you have to add more if/else statements in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You could certainly have logic in your views that either calls a method on a Ruby object or treats it like a hash, but it would be cleaner (and a better practice) for the method to return the same type of objects.

So, in the appropriate branch of you if/elsif/else, either you convert the Ruby objects to Hashes or the Hashes to Ruby objects.

The first is the easiest, turning Ruby objects into hashes:

`@part_groups = @part_groups.map(&:attributes)`

The second, to turn a Hash into an instance of your class you can do

`@part_groups = @part_groups.map { |pg| PartGroup.instantiate pg }`.

Of course, you *could* just treat the Ruby object like a Hash: `part_group['name']` will give you what you want from either the hash or the Ruby object. But then the method would still be returning different things, potentially leading to the same problem or just confusion in the future.

Comment: This great. I ideally I would like to convert ruby objects. The problem is that my model has a bunch or relations and my query intern in using a bunch or joins. So when I convert it to a ruby object I am only getting the stuff from part_groups and not the relations. How can I include the relations into the object?